# To native English speakers, "I'll take it as take out"

Tags: expressions

If I order a coffee and want to take it out. (To go..) 
The expression "I'll take it as take out." makes sense? 
And use that in common?

Comment: Probably, "I'll have it as a take out"

Comment: Note that the phrase "take out" itself is common in some countries and not others. In Australia we say "takeaway", and in the context of a coffee order I would say, "One coffee to take away please." I think people would understand what you mean, but to me it sounds a bit clunky to use the word "take" twice like that.

Comment: thank you for your comments @BellaSwan

Comment: and thank you @nnnnnn for the detail feedback!!

Comment: In the US we would be more likely to say “May I have that to go?” “This order is to go” etc. “take out” is more like a type of dining to me as in “let’s get take out”